# Increment clickcount label value in tableview cell whenever i click that row

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `clickCount` label in my `CustomCell`, I want to increment its value on `rowClick`.
 Suppose my current value of this label is 5 then I want to increment it on row click and update it at the same time in table. 
I am using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` for this but it doesn't update the label text , `cellForRowAtIndexpath` is called after this and it resets the label with previous value.

Comment: You have to maintain one local variable to save last count  to compare with new count and add observer on each click.

Comment: You have to update into your data.

Comment: You could either store the value and increment it in the custom cell class, or you could store the data in the view controller class, increment it and then reload the cell.

Comment: Reloading the cell with reloadrowatindexpath calls cellforrowatindexpath which again resets my label text , it just shows my updated text for a second when the row animates at the time of reloading then again resets it to previous value

Answer (score 0):

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      NSString *Str= [[ArrProductInCart objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Product_Count"];
int Quantity=[Str intValue];
        Quantity=Quantity+1;

        StrQuantity=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Quantity];

        CGPoint correctedPoint = [sender convertPoint:sender.bounds.origin toView:tbl];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tbl indexPathForRowAtPoint:correctedPoint];

        [self updateCell:indexPath withValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",StrQuantity]];

    }

    - (void)updateCell:(NSIndexPath *)indexpathValue withValue:(NSString *)value
    {
        NSDictionary* dict = [Array_That_maintain_Count_Values objectAtIndex:indexpathValue.row];
        [dict setValue:value forKey:@"Product_Count"];
        [Array_That_maintain_Count_Values replaceObjectAtIndex:indexpathValue.row withObject:dict];

        [tbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpathValue] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
```

Now Array_That_maintain_Count_Values will contain the count of clicks at each indexpath.
Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Only when i am on that view , it should increment whenever i click on row

Comment: @Trapti is you work done ?? Code is working fine according to your case?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a variable to store the count. Depends on how many rows do you want to be like this. If there are more than 1, you need a local array like `[Int]`. Say you have one cell at section 0, row 0 that you want this feature, and it's initial value is 5. So you will have

```
var count = 5

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! Cell

    cell.label.text = String(count)

    return cell
}
```

Now you need to handle the cell click event. When the cell is clicked, you want first increase this count, and then reload the cell so that the `cellForRow` is triggered to update the label. So you will need

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {
        self.count ++
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .none)
    }
}
```